# Gnu Make with two file list

Tags: list, makefile

I have a Gnu Makefile with two lists:

```
LIST1=file01.cpp file02.cpp file03.cpp ......
LIST2=file10.cpp file11.cpp file12.cpp .....
```

I want to compile each of the files, but for each list I want to use different flags.

I could specify a rule for each file. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare make variables on a target basis. So:

```
LIST1=file01.cpp file02.cpp file03.cpp ......
LIST2=file10.cpp file11.cpp file12.cpp .....
OBJ1 = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(LIST1))
OBJ2 = $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(LIST2))

$(OBJ1): CXXFLAGS = <flags-for-list1>

$(OBJ2): CXXFLAGS = <flags-for-list2>

all: $(OBJ1) $(OBJ2)
$(OBJ1) $(OBJ2): %.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

is probably close from what you want.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have enough reputation to uptick the score

Comment: But you can accept the answer, it also helps filtering the question as "answered".